# Relationship between available Counties and subscription services on App Store Connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, subscription

As my app actually supports one language only (but not English), I am gonna change the available countries and regions setting on App Store Connect from all of the countries and regions to the one country.

However, I realized my apps already has some users in the other countries, on top of that, some of them has been subscribing the paid-service.

Anyone who knows what happens to the subscriptions which the users already have in the other countries if I stop providing the area users with my app?

I'd especially like to know if the subscription will be cancelled automagically or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple Still charges you as the equivalent value with respect of the currency of your selected county

https://support.apple.com/en-hk/HT201389

https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/

[Testing localized in-app purchases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37638117/testing-localized-in-app-purchases)

Purchase Item Creation( Consumables and Subscription)

https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devae49fb316

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer. Can I ask to let me know any official documents that mention about it if you don’t mind?